# Does decapitation for sure kill a vampire?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, vampire-the-requiem-2e

This seems almost a ridiculous question, but since I can't find any rules regarding it...

Does cutting the head off a vampire for sure kill it? or if they had enough vitae could they regrow the head? or rejoin the head?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Page 7, "Truth and Lies"

> VAMPIRES ARE IMMORTAL: Almost. There's very little that can harm us. Sun. Fire. Maybe a heart broken by a wooden stake, **followed by losing your head to a hacksaw.** Other than that, the years stretch out like a banquet.

Although the argument could be made that a head severed could be reattached like a limb (if Vitae were spent fast enough) decapitation does lead to Final Death.

Comment: Notice that first it mentions the wooden stake, which would prevent the vampire from spending vitae to regenerate.

Comment: @arthexis True. Or just a sign that most vampires wouldn't sit still for a slow beheading.